# jpype ignores jar and has empty class path

Tags: python, java, jar, jpype

I have a jar in the directory `~/jars/my_jar.jar` and want to load it with

```py
import jpype
from jpype import imports
jpype.startJVM(classpath="~/jars/my_jar.jar")
```

Then calling standard java classes works fine:

```py
from java.util import Random
Random().nextInt()
```

But the class path is empty `jpype.getClassPath()`.
Also importing classes from my jar fails.

```py
from my.own.package import MyClass
// Java package 'my' not found
```

How do I specify the class path and import my jar?

Answer (score 0):

Replaced `"~/jars/my_jar.jar"` with `"jars/my_jar.jar"` as classpath and it works now.